# Is it possible to use dataset in VB6?

Tags: vb6, dataset

Is it possible to use dataset in VB6? If yes then what is it's reference library?

Comment: It is probably possible by wrapping .NET code with a Com Callable Wrapper, but you are probably better off with DataSet's grandad, called ADODB.RecordSet, which is a native COM data access component.

Comment: Great. ADODB.RecordSet is what I need.
Thanks a lot @nonnb

Comment: Creating a Com Callable Wrapper isn't very feasible because you'll have to create an additional layer which exposes objects that VB6 can understand (probably ADO). This means you'll have none of the benefits of ADO.NET and an additional layer causing complexity and slower performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dataset, you can use ADODB.RecordSet, you can get more about [ADODB.RecordSet from here.](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_recordset.asp)